# multiple ips for wildcard domains using dnsmasq's config format

Tags: domain-name-system, wildcard, dnsmasq

dnsmasq is capable of assigning multiple static ips to one host when using the hosts file:

```
1.2.3.4 bla.com
4.5.6.7 bla.com
```

nslookup:

```
Name:   example.com
Address: 1.2.3.4
Name:   example.com
Address: 4.5.6.7
```

However, wildcards in hosts are not possible. dnsmasq's own config file format allows them though:

```
address=/example.com/1.2.3.4
address=/example.com/5.6.7.8
```

The problem here is: a lookup will always return `5.6.7.8` only. `1.2.3.4` is getting overwritten

Is there a approach combining these 2 attempts? It seems weird that dnsmasq is capable of assigning multiple ips to one host when using hosts format, but not when using their own config file format.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this discussion](http://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/pipermail/dnsmasq-discuss/2013q3/007465.html), there is no way to do this in dnsmasq without substantial code changes, unfortunately.